# After Navigate2 Method returns S_OK Stuck at READYSTATE of READYSTATE_LOADING

Tags: mfc, iwebbrowser2, docview, readystate

I am working on a MFC Document View architecture application which has multiple documents and views and a tabbed window interface.

I have been tasked with making an automatic switch to another tab on the press of the OK button in one of the other tabs.  When the other tab is clicked on it uses a C++ wrapper over IWebBrowser2 to navigate to a specific web page.

When this is done manually by clicking on the tab everything is fine and the webpage within the view loads successfully.

In my first attempt at doing this the tab successfully switched in response to a call to

```
 AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessageToDescendants(SOME_MESSAGE, ...);
```

however by sending this windows message at the wrong point the application would crash once control returned because the chain of events caused the (modeless) dialog (*) that 
sent the message, to no longer exist.

I then found the correct place to make the call, but now when the other tab is activated, it no longer displays the webpage as it should.

To debug this problem I added code to check the READYSTATE in both the situation where it works and the situation where it does not.  When the page fails to load (despite the call to Navigate2 returning S_OK), the READYSTATE just stays at READYSTATE_LOADING.

Unfortunately now I am to many edits away from when I had it partially working.

I have added TRACE statements to the most obvious events such as OnSetFocus,  CView::OnActivateView but all traces come out in the same order despite the behaviour being different

* hosted in the view

Comment: what is the message you sent with SendMessageToDescendants? It is going to mess up big time if the message id is conflicting with toolbar/statusbar/webbrowser' messages.

Comment: Its an application specific message.  I don't think that it conflicts with other messages.  There is a toolbar button that when clicked also initiates a switch to another tab, but when it is clicked the web page successfully loads.